# Python mySQL - escaping quotes

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have seen this question asked in various ways on this website, but none of them exactly addressed my issue.

I have an sql statement with single quotes inside it, and am trying to use recommended practices before making database queries with it. So the statement is like

```
val2="abc 'dostuff'" 
sql="INSERT INTO TABLE_A(COL_A,COL_B) VALUES(%s,'%s')" %(val1, val2)
a_cursor.execute(sql)
```

However, when I run this, I get..

```
ProgrammingError: (1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dostuff'.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks very much
Nupur

Comment: try using multiline quotes. """ or '''

Answer (score 47):

Use parameters instead of string interpolation to ensure that your values are properly escaped by the database connector:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_A(COL_A,COL_B) VALUES(%s, %s)"
a_cursor.execute(sql, (val1, val2))
```

The mysqldb sql parameter style uses the same syntax as used by the python string formatting operator, which is a little confusing.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for this!  I had read elsewhere on Stackoverflow that, under Python, the query could not be parameterised.  I am so pleased to have stumbled across your answer!

Comment: Values are not being substituted. I am using python3

Comment: That’s not enough info. What input? What expected output? What happens instead? What MySQL library, what version? Python 3 is probably not a factor here.

Comment: How can I do the same thing with the columns? I have a list of columns I want to use, and I tried to do so the same thing but it used quotes instead of backticks for the field names

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 column names are not data; the point of SQL parameters is to prevent data from being interpreted as anything but data, so putting column names in parameters specifically won’t work. You’d have to use string formatting, but you have to be extremely careful not to use untrusted data when you do that. Better to use a SQL generating library like SQLAlchemy in that case.