# Escaping characters for MySQL for UPDATE operation using Python/MySQLdb

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, escaping, mysql-python

**Note:** I have discovered that re.escape(string) will do escaping but man, does it escape a lot. I can use that if I have to, but I am leaving the question open for any other ideas, also in case this is stumbled upon in the future.

I found a great S.O. answer here regarding INSERTing data into MySQL with Python ( I'm using 2.7 ) where the data contains apostrophes : [Python mySQL - escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902862/python-mysql-escaping-quotes)

In a nutshell, the S.O. answer was to do this.....

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_A(COL_A,COL_B) VALUES(%s, %s)"
a_cursor.execute(sql, (val1, val2))
```

I need to do this for an UPDATE though. My current method is ....

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET COL_A='R', COL_B='%s', COL_C='%s', COL_D='%s', COL_E='%s',COL_F='%s' WHERE COL_G='%s'" % (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6)
cur.execute(sql)
```

Error I get is: 1064 error in syntax.

The problem is val5, it's a blob of text that contains apostrophes ( and who knows what else ) and I need a way to escape special characters before UPDATE. I have sneaking suspicion that I'll just have to do this massive routine where I have to specifically spell out characters as I tend to find them but I'd like to see if anyone else has had this issue.

I appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: I ended up using a function instead to just escape the single apostrophe. I am not going to pick my own as the answer though.

Comment: Are all those fancy quotes in your actual code or did you use an editor somewhere that inserted them? `‘R’` is not valid because of those quotes, use `'R'`..

Comment: Not sure, but I am only using regular single quotes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL parameters; these are escaped and quoted *for you*; note that the `INSERT` query you found uses this technique. SQL parameter escaping handle apostrophes properly, and makes sure you don't fall victim to a SQL injection attack, among other advantages.

From your `sql` value, remove the quoting around your parameters, and pass in the values as parameters, do *not* use interpolation:

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET COL_A='R', COL_B=%s, COL_C=%s, COL_D=%s, COL_E=%s, COL_F=%s WHERE COL_G=%s"
cur.execute(sql, (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6))
```

or using a multiline string for better readability:

```
sql = """
    UPDATE table
    SET
        COL_A='R',
        COL_B=%s,
        COL_C=%s,
        COL_D=%s,
        COL_E=%s,
        COL_F=%s
    WHERE COL_G=%s"
cur.execute(sql, (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6))
```

As an aside, `re.escape()` is a function to handle escaping of strings you want to treat as literal values *in a regular expression*. The function is entirely unsuited for escaping values in a SQL setting.