# While inserting data in MySql, getting error in String for single quote

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to insert the data in MySql DB, it is giving the error in case of a string.

I am trying to insert the data in MySql DB, it is working fine if the string doesn't contain any single quote but when I am trying to insert the string with a single quote, then it is giving the error in case of string

```
content_dict = xmltodict.parse(request.data)
        cur=mydb.cursor()
        for key in content_dict:
            cur.execute("insert into MyXMLApi(xmlData) values({})".format(str(content_dict[key])))
            mydb.commit()
```

> Error: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't forget me
>   this weekend!')' at line 1

this error is occuring when I am trying to insert this line:

```
Don't forget me this weekend!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python mySQL - escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902862/python-mysql-escaping-quotes)